# missing inhibit sleep applet for unity

Tags: unity, applet

I am looking for an INHIBIT SLEEP applet for Ubuntu 11.10 unity, to enable me watching movies on Google without having to move the mouse or change power management.

Answer (score 1):

The program you're searching for is called caffeine.
They have a ppa so you can install it with ease, check:

https://launchpad.net/~caffeine-developers/+archive/ppa